# Can uglify-js remove require and export statements?

Tags: javascript, node.js, uglifyjs, uglifyjs2

I'm using uglify-js to minify the source code. I want to remove

**const moment = require('moment');**

**const PouchDB = require('pouchdb');**

**module.exports = Chart;**

statements of the original source code. Is it possible? Or is there any other compressor tool supports this?

I use the code as below in Node.js.

```
'use strict'
const moment = require('moment');
const PouchDB = require('pouchdb');
const defaultcachetime = 12; // hours
const VERIFIED = 3;
const UNIQUCOUNTER = 1;


var caches = {};
var cachechange = {};

function Chart(path, credentials, user){

}

module.exports = Chart;
```

The output contains

```
"use strict";const moment=require("moment"),PouchDB=require("pouchdb") return a},module.exports=Chart;
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: You might want to look into something like webpack.  https://webpack.js.org/

Comment: @Keith can you give me an example with webpack how to do this?  thanks.

Comment: Webpacks documentation is pretty good, suggest you try this -> https://webpack.js.org/concepts/  any problems getting this to work, come back here again with problems you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to overcome the challenge by doing

1. [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) to convert **Require** and **Import** keywords to FE parsable code.
2. Minify JS code with [Uglify](https://www.uglifyjs.net/)

Hope it helps with anyone who might be facing the same challenge.